# Shiny: passing reactive values to xtable options in renderTable

Tags: shiny, xtable

I am having a problem with a format of a table.

Let's say I want to control the number of digits of a table with a numeric input. It seems that the options of the table are rendered when I launch the application but not with reactive values. is this true??

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---


```{r, echo=FALSE}
inputPanel(
  numericInput("n_digits", label = "Number of digits:",
              min = 0, max = 5, value = 1)
)

renderTable({
a<-rep(1.1,3)
b<-rep(2.22,3)
c<-rep(3.333,3)
cbind(a,b,c)
}, digits=c(0,rep(input$n_digits,3)))
```
````

This could also be helpful to passing other options when the number of columns is not fixed and depends on a variable